# vue js validation for large forms

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, vuelidate

i am new to  vue js and i wondering how i can validate a form  with  differentes inputs type and having  at  least 20  questions ,when  using vuelidate i have to manually set the  validation rule form  each fields and also  put them in the data section but that seem  to  be  very  inefficient for  me so i am  asking how to  validate large forms in vue js could someone help me?
validating a form  with  20 questions in vue js
this is what i saw ont

```
     import { useVuelidate } from '@vuelidate/core'
     import { required, email } from '@vuelidate/validators'

     export default {
      setup () {
      return { v$: useVuelidate() }
    },
    data () {
    return {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      contact: {
        email: ''
       }
     }
    } ,
    validations () {
    return {
      firstName: { required }, // Matches this.firstName
      lastName: { required }, // Matches this.lastName
      contact: {
        email: { required, email } // Matches this.contact.email
        }
      }
     }
   }
```

Comment: and also i want to  know if it is to  do  validation the client side or on the backend?

Comment: it worth  mentionning that iam  using the  option API  with  vue js 3